# Whats the point of #define?

Tags: c#

They have to be placed on the top of your .cs file. You cant create those guys dynamically at runtime and you cant give them a value or change their value because there is no value at all so whats the point of #define keyword?

Here is an example:

```
#define DEBUG
#define MYTEST
using System;
public class MyClass 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
#if (DEBUG && !MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG is defined");
#elif (!DEBUG && MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("MYTEST is defined");
#elif (DEBUG && MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG and MYTEST are defined");
#else
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG and MYTEST are not defined");
#endif
    }
}
```

Both are defined on top so why having all those ifs anyway?

Can somebody tell me scenarios where define is usefull?

Sorry if this is a duplicate just let me know in comments if so and I ll remove this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is *condiional compialtion*.

Like:

```
#ifdef x64     
.... 
#else
....
#endif


#ifdef KIOSK
   fullScreen  =true; 
#else
   fullScreen  =false;
#endif
```

You create condition for *compile time*, so your binaries will not change at runtime, but
will fit exact requirements of your target ambient you are compiling for.It could be whatever you want, it's up to you decide name and *semantics* of what you `#define`.

**EDIT**.

Example: you have a program that acess low level windows API, and you have to support 
x86 and x64 versions. In this case you may want that in *binaries* (so after compilation) of your program for 32bit, there is no any evidence of 64bit functions. So you may write

```
#ifdef x64 //conditional compilation symbol defined by YOU 
   DriverInfo GetDriverInfo64(..) {...} //64bit 
#else
   DriverInfo GetDriverInfo(..) {...}   //32bit
#endif
```

Comment: If you have to define them on top then for each compilation they are gonna be there. They are hardcoded. So what do you mean with conditional there?

Comment: How does that answer the question? Sure, you show examples for preprocessor usage ... **but that was not the question**. I am actually baffled it got so many upvotes in so few time.

Comment: You do not. You can also define them in project properties depending on whether you have it a compile or release build.

Comment: that you can in case of one define declare a function, that can be missed in other conditional compilation. missed from binaries. for example x64 conndition: you may want your dll does not have any 64bit targeting API functions if you compile for 32bit. *that is a place* where you use #define.

Comment: @dev hedgehog: In your example they are hardcoded, but you can also define them in your project settings or as argument for the compiler. For example, `DEBUG` is automatically defined in VS when using the debug build settings. So you can include/exclude code **at compile time**.

Comment: Another great example (imo) is the `NETFX_CORE` symbol that is set automatically, depending on whether you're using a classic .NET project template or a modern Windows Store project template. Useful for writing class libraries that need to support both environments.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define these symbols with `#define`, you can set them globally in the project settings or per compiler argument. But sometimes it comes in handy when you can alter the value of a symbol (set/unset) for a single file, for testing or debugging purposes. Then `#define` will be your friend :)

Comment: Ahhh ok I didnt know this before. This makes sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the two #define statement at the top. If you use Visual Studio to compile, you can then have the option to turn the debug on or not. If you turn on debug, the compiler will know what section to have in your code and which to leave out.

Suppose you have DEBUG turned on, your code will look like:

```
using System;
public class MyClass 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG is defined");
    }
}
```